# swagger 3.0 define pattern to prevent duplicate

Tags: swagger

Hi i try to define string pattern like this:

```
components:
    patterns:
        unsigned: ^\d+$
```

to use by

```
properties:
    somePropertyName:
        type: integer:
        pattern: 
            $ref: '#/components/patterns/unsigned
```

Cant find right syntax to define some string *variable*/*const*.
It is possible?

Some example with twice duplicate of same patterns:

```
    paths:
        /location:
            get:
              summary: Get location label by lat/lng
              parameters:
                - name: latitude
                  in: query
                  required: true
                  schema:
                    type: number
                    format: float
                    pattern: '^(\+|-)?(?:90(?:(?:\.0{1,6})?)|(?:[0-9]|[1-8][0-9])(?:(?:\.[0-9]{1,6})?))$'
                - name: longitude
                  in: query
                  required: true
                  schema:
                    type: number
                    format: float
                    pattern: '^(\+|-)?(?:180(?:(?:\.0{1,6})?)|(?:[0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-7][0-9])(?:(?:\.[0-9]{1,6})?))$'
              ...
    components:   
        schemas:    
            Location:
              type: object
              properties:
                ...
                latitude:
                  type: number
                  format: float
                  pattern: '^(\+|-)?(?:90(?:(?:\.0{1,6})?)|(?:[0-9]|[1-8][0-9])(?:(?:\.[0-9]{1,6})?))$'
                longitude:
                  type: number
                  format: float
                  pattern: '^(\+|-)?(?:180(?:(?:\.0{1,6})?)|(?:[0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-7][0-9])(?:(?:\.[0-9]{1,6})?))$'
                ...
```

I have X more queries where i want to reuse this patterns and i dont want to refactor X places after possible change of pattern in future.

Or this:

```
OpenHours:
      type: object
      properties:
        MondayOpen:
          type: string
          pattern: '([01]?\d|2[0-3]):([0-5]?\d)'
        MondayClose:
          type: string
          pattern: '([01]?\d|2[0-3]):([0-5]?\d)'
        TuesdayOpen:
          type: string
          pattern: '([01]?\d|2[0-3]):([0-5]?\d)'
        TuesdayClose:
          type: string
          pattern: '([01]?\d|2[0-3]):([0-5]?\d)'
        WednesdayOpen:
          type: string
          pattern: '([01]?\d|2[0-3]):([0-5]?\d)'
        WednesdayClose:
          type: string
          pattern: '([01]?\d|2[0-3]):([0-5]?\d)'
        ThursdayOpen:
          type: string
          pattern: '([01]?\d|2[0-3]):([0-5]?\d)'
        ThursdayClose:
          type: string
          pattern: '([01]?\d|2[0-3]):([0-5]?\d)'
        FridayOpen:
          type: string
          pattern: '([01]?\d|2[0-3]):([0-5]?\d)'
        FridayClose:
          type: string
          pattern: '([01]?\d|2[0-3]):([0-5]?\d)'
        SaturdayOpen:
          type: string
          pattern: '([01]?\d|2[0-3]):([0-5]?\d)'
        SaturdayClose:
          type: string
          pattern: '([01]?\d|2[0-3]):([0-5]?\d)'
        SundayOpen:
          type: string
          pattern: '([01]?\d|2[0-3]):([0-5]?\d)'
        SundayClose:
          type: string
          pattern: '([01]?\d|2[0-3]):([0-5]?\d)'
```

Comment: `pattern` applies to strings only. Also, there's no `components/patterns` in OpenAPI 3.0. Can you explain what exactly you are trying to achieve?

Comment: I try to reuse latitude longtitude pattern in some object and many get queries.

Comment: Can you add some examples of the objects and get queries with the latitude values? Are the longitude values numbers (`44.5`) or strings (`"44.5"`)? The more details, the easier it is to come up with an answer.

Comment: @Helen i add some examples. My challenge is "Only one place to change after possible refactor of pattern". I find in some article info like this "If request do not changes in db it must be GET", but in GET use objects is not possible